# Is there a good way use a read only hashmap on cuda?

Tags: cuda

I am really new to programming and Cuda. Basically I have a C function that reads a list of data and then checks each item against a hashmap (I'm using [uthash](http://uthash.sourceforge.net/) for this in C).  It works well but I want to run this process in Cuda (once it gets the value for the hash key then it does a lot of processing), but I'm unsure the best way to create a read only hash function that's as quick as possible in Cuda.

### Background

Basically I'm trying to value a very very large batch of portfolio as quickly as possible. I get several million portfolio constantly that are in the form of two lists. One has the stock name and the other has the weight.  I then use the stock name to look up a hashtable to get other data(value, % change,etc..) and then process it based on the weight.  On a CPU in plain C it takes about 8 minutes so I am interesting in trying it on a GPU.

I have read and done the examples in `cuda by example` so I believe I know how to do most of this except the hash function(there is one in the appendix but it seems focused on adding to it while I only really want it as a reference since it'll never change. I might be rough around the edges in `cuda for example` so maybe there is something I'm missing that is helpful for me in this situation, like using textual or some special form of memory for this).   How would I structure this for best results should each block have its own access to the hashmap or should each thread or is one good enough for the entire GPU?

### Edit

Sorry just to clarify, I'm only using C. Worst case I'm willing to use another language but ideally I'd like something that I can just natively put on the GPU once and have all future threads read to it since to process my data I'll need to do it in several large batches).

Comment: How much non-memory lookup processing do you do after reading the data in from hash table?

Comment: @dbaupp not very much which was a problem.  Roger was able to help me get a favorable result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is some thoughts on potential performance issues of using a hash map on a GPU, to back up my comment about keeping the hash map on the CPU.

NVIDIA GPUs run threads in groups of 32 threads, called warps. To get good performance, each of the threads in a warp must be doing essentially the same thing. That is, they must run the same instructions and they must read from memory locations that are close to each other.

I think a hash map may break with both of these rules, possibly slowing the GPU down so much that there's no use in keeping the hash map on the GPU.

Consider what happens when the 32 threads in a warp run:

- First, each thread has to create a hash of the stock name. If these names differ in length, this will involve a different number of rounds in the hashing loop for the different lengths and all the threads in the warp must wait for the hash of the longest name to complete. Depending on the hashing algorithm, there might different paths that the code can take inside the hashing algorithm. Whenever the different threads in a warp need to take different paths, the same code must run multiple times (once for each code path). This is called warp divergence.
- When all the threads in warp each have obtained a hash, each thread will then have to read from different locations in slow global memory (designated by the hashes). The GPU runs optimally when each of the 32 threads in the warp read in a tight, coherent pattern. But now, each thread is reading from an essentially random location in memory. This could cause the GPU to have to serialize all the threads, potentially dropping the performance to 1/32 of the potential.
- The memory locations that the threads read are hash buckets. Each potentially containing a different number of hashes, again causing the threads in the warp to have to do different things. They may then have to branch out again, each to a random location, to get the actual structures that are mapped.

If you instead keep the stock names and data structures in a hash map on the CPU, you can use the CPU to put together arrays of information that are stored in the exact pattern that the GPU is good at handling. Depending on how busy the CPU is, you may be able to do this while the GPU is processing the previously submitted work.

This also gives you an opportunity to change the array of structures (AoS) that you have on the CPU to a structure of arrays (SoA) for the GPU. If you are not familiar with this concept, essentially, you convert:

```
my_struct {
  int a;
  int b;
};
my_struct my_array_of_structs[1000];
```

to:

```
struct my_struct {
  int a[1000];
  int b[1000];
} my_struct_of_arrays;
```

This puts all the `a`'s adjacent to each other in memory so that when the 32 threads in a warp get to the instruction that reads `a`, all the values are neatly laid out next to each other, causing the entire warp to be able to load the values very quickly. The same is true for the `b`'s, of course.

Answer (score 1):

There is a hash_map extension for CUDA Thrust, in the [cuda-thrust-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/cuda-thrust-extensions/) library. I have not tried it.

Comment: Thanks Roger. I'm not sure if it was you or someone else who posted that in another question but I have seen that library.  The problem is I'm using just C not c++..I thought thrust was c++ only?

Comment: Thrust is part of CUDA C, which is C++...ish :) You can use Thrust in your .cu files. Oh, and it wasn't me.

Comment: You help me so much that even if the answer is not from you I still associate it with your wisdom. I'll give your recommendation a shot and let you know.  I am very very new to programming in general and was trying to minimize any problems with integration of languages so I was hesitant to use thrust but I'll play with the samples on their site so far it works pretty well with just nvcc {filename}

Comment: Thrust, as with STL, may be a bit daunting at first. Also, since it is inspired by STL, you may be able to find out how to do things with Thrust by seeing how they're done with C++ and STL.

Comment: Hey Roger, I have been struggling with this library and I don't think it works.  The test file thats included fails everytime I run it and I get warnings that its referring to deprecated headers.  There appears to be a implementation in cudpp, I'm going to try that and will update you on the results.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I think a hash map would probably not run with great performance on a GPU, so that might be why it's hard to find a good implementation. Have you considered doing the lookups on the CPU and send a plain array of value and change data to the GPU? You might get better performance even if the arrays that you send to the GPU contain lots of duplicates.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12340/discussion-between-roger-dahl-and-lostsoul)

Comment: I'm in the chat.  I can try that. Right now I have a cpu version of my code and it uses uthash. I am not sure how do what you described, basically I have millions of portfolio & the work of calculating the %change is easy but the volume of portfolios is what makes the cpu slow. I think its easy for a gpu to do but the lookups are becoming the problem. Don't games have a similar problem? on a map it needs to lookup terrian to know to make water blue and land green, isn't that just a hashmap of "water"="blue" or something?

Comment: Hey Sorry Roger, I'm back if your around I'm back in the chat.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your hash map is so large, I think it can be replaced by a database, mysql or other products will all be OK, they probably will be fast than hash map design by yourself. And I agree with Roger's viewpoint, it is not suitable to move it to GPU, it consumes too large device memory (may be not capable to contain it) and it is terribly slow for kernel function access global memory on device.

Further more, which part of your program takes 8 minutes, finding in hash map or process on weight? If it is the latter, may be it can be accelerated by GPU.

Best regards!